# how to use manifest tags

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest

i set in my AndroidManiifest.xml

```
 android:installLocation="internalOnly"
```

my question is if the internal memory is full and when we want to install the app to device can be installed on external memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#install) is rather clear on that:

> The application must be installed on the internal device storage only. If this is set, the application will never be installed on the external storage. If the internal storage is full, then the system will not install the application. This is also the default behavior if you do not define android:installLocation.

Answer (score 1):

Using `android:installLocation="auto"` if  the internal memory is full the system will install the app on the external memory.